# Confusing about loop diagram

Tags: loops

The question :

[image]

As i understand, the loop works like this :

```
k = 1
while true 
{ 
    if k <= N 
    {
        if X == A(k)     
            exit loop
        else
            k = k + 1 
    }
    else 
        exit loop
}
```

with the initial value is 1 and increment is 1, the loop will end if x = A(k)

So why is the given answer is A :

> If the same value as Xexists in two places ofthe array, the 1st and
> N-th elements, kis  set to 1

I don't get it !

Comment: Can you give us the link to the source?

Comment: @Nullpointer you can find it here : http://www.itpec.org/download/FeApr2007.zip , the file is 2007Apr_FE_AM_Questions.pdf , the question number is 16

Comment: If the first element of the array equals X, then the loop is left before `k` is incremented – so it keeps the value it was initialized with, which is 1.

Comment: @CBroe what if the n-th element equals X instead the first ?

Comment: Then the value of `k` will be `N`, of course …

Comment: @CBroe but the answer say if A(k) equals x, k is set to 1 ???

Comment: @CBroe and k is not N , i think, k is <= N , technically, there is no part that assigns k = N directly in the diagram , so K may be = N not k will be N definitely

Comment: No, it doesn’t say that – it says when when the first 1st _and_ N-th element equal X, k will be 1. If you take out the first part (1st element being equal X), then of course that changes the answer.

Comment: _“there is no part that assigns k = N directly in the diagram”_ – no, but k gets incremented by 1 N-1 times …

Comment: @CBroe ahh i see, the question mentioned AND, not OR, a sneaky one, thanks alot, you mind answering it so i will mark it as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first element of the array equals X, then the loop is left before `k` is incremented – so it keeps the value it was initialized with, which is 1.

Comment: one more question please, why the answer say "two places", if the first equals x, the program left, so why they say "two places" ( the first and n-th elements)

Comment: Well probably to try and confuse you a little bit, resp. require you to think about it a little harder …?

Comment: It only says the value X exists in two places, 1st and N-th – this only makes a statement about what exists _before_ the “program” starts – that is a given, no matter what the programm does with those values _afterwards_ …

Comment: ahhhhh, now i totally understand, the n-th is an extra thing to make me confused, sorry, first time took these kind of questions ! Never gotten any real education before !